# Trouble with Fourier Transform using fftpack5.1

Tags: fortran, fft, fftpack

I have an issue using the FFTPACK5.1 in Fortran 90 which contains subroutines to compute discrete Fourier transforms. I manage to install it and use the routines but when I'm checking if everything is ok with a simple sine wave with a frequency **A** I get a non zero coefficient not at A (in frequency space, in the spectrum) but at **2A**. There is a shift in the spectrum and I don't understand why. I'm almost sure (but I have doubts) that I compute correctly the frequency axis steps:

With N being the number of points of my original sine wave, and Fech my sample frequency I compute the frequency axis steps as df(i)=Fech(i-1)/N.

I'm using the **rfft1f** routine, so if someone has an experience with it and knows my problem I will be really greatful to understand what is wrong here.

Here is my code:

```
! n: number of samples in the discret signal
integer ( kind = 4 ), parameter :: n = 4096
real, parameter :: deuxpi=6.283185307
!frequence is the frequence of the signal
!fech is the frequence of sampling
real :: frequence,fech 
integer :: kk
! r is the signal i want to process
! t is the built time and f is the built frequency
real ( kind = 4 ) r(n),t(n),f(n)


!Arrays routines need to work (internal recipe):
real ( kind = 4 ), allocatable, dimension ( : ) :: work
real ( kind = 4 ), allocatable, dimension ( : ) :: wsave

!size of arrays wsave and work for internal recipe 
lensav = n + int ( log ( real ( n, kind = 4 ) ) / log ( 2.0E+00 ) ) + 4
lenwrk = n
allocate ( work(1:lenwrk) )
allocate ( wsave(1:lensav) )


! initializes rttft1f, wsave array
call rfft1i ( n, wsave, lensav, ier )


frequence=0.5
fech=20

! I built here the signal
do kk=1,n
t (kk) = (kk-1) / (fech)
f (kk) = fech*(kk-1) / n
r (kk) = sin( deuxpi * t(kk) * frequence  ) 
end do


!and I call the rfft1f to build the Discrete Fourier Transform:
call rfft1f ( n, inc, r, lenr, wsave, lensav, work, lenwrk, ier )

!I get back r which contains now the fourier coefficients and plot it
```

I'm expecting with a simple sine wave to have a dirac at the frequency at 0.5 (cf code) but instead I get a dirac at 1., in the frequency domain. Besides, the spectrum looks odd... Here is what I get:

[image: Spectrum]

Comment: Show your code, the expected behavior and the actual behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is typical of routines computing discrete fourier transform of real-valued sequences, the resulting complex valued spectrum is returned for only half the spectrum. To fit the values into the original N-element array, only the real-part of the first value (which is always real) is returned. Similarly in the case of even values of `n`, the real-part of the `n`/2-th complex value (which is also always real) is returned. For all other complex values, the real and imaginary parts are interleaved.

So for even `n`, the corresponding frequency is given by:

```
r(1)       -> 0
r(2), r(3) -> Delta
r(4), r(5) -> 2*Delta
...
r(n)       -> (n/2)*Delta
```

And for odd `n`:

```
r(1)        -> 0
r(2), r(3)  -> Delta
r(4), r(5)  -> 2*Delta
...
r(n-1),r(n) -> ((n-1)/2) * Delta
```

where Delta is given as `fech/n`.

To plot the complex values, you'd probably want to plot either the real (indices 1,2,4,6,...) & imaginary (indices 3,5,7,...) parts as two separate graphs, or the amplitude & phase (again as two separate graphs).

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, if i understand it is because it's spanning the original  n array size from -n/2 to n/2 and because of symmetry i just get back into my signal r the positive part and that's why i need to divide by 2?

Comment: `n`-point FFT takes `n` time-domain values, and transforms them into `n` complex frequency-domain values. Frequency step is then `fech/n`. When mapping half the spectrum you have `n/2` points covering `fech/2`, so again step is `(fech/2)/(n/2) = fech/n`. 
The main reason for the divide by 2 is because of the storing of complex values into an array of floating point numbers (real/imaginary parts alternation).